# Update / Edit Sharepoint 2007 User Information List UIL

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, user-information-list

How to update Sharepoint 2007 User Information List (UIL) through C# code? 
My code works fine when logged in as an administrator, however when logged in as a simple user the code throws "Access Denied" error because simple user can't access UIL. 
I need some way to get the simple user to edit HIS OWN information (say EMAIL) in the UIL.
Please help. It's very important. 
My code is like:

```
string var_UserName = myUsername;
string var_newemail = mynewemail@abc.com;
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                {
                    using (SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site)
                   {
                        SPWeb curWeb = site.OpenWeb();

                        SPList userList = SPContext.Current.Web.SiteUserInfoList;
                        StringBuilder queryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                        queryBuilder.Append(@"<Query>");
                        queryBuilder.Append(@"<OrderBy>");
                        queryBuilder.Append(@"<FieldRef Name='Title' />");
                        queryBuilder.Append(@"</OrderBy>");
                        queryBuilder.Append(@"<Where>");
                        queryBuilder.Append(@"<Eq>");
                        queryBuilder.Append(@"<FieldRef Name='Title' />");
                        queryBuilder.Append(@"<Value Type='Text'>" + var_UserName + "</Value>");
                        queryBuilder.Append(@"</Eq>");
                        queryBuilder.Append(@"</Where>");
                        queryBuilder.Append(@"</Query>");
                        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                        query.Query = queryBuilder.ToString();
                        SPListItemCollection oSPListItemCollection = userList.GetItems(query);
                        SPField field = userList.Fields.GetField("E-Mail");

                        foreach (SPItem item in oSPListItemCollection)
                        {
                            if (item["Title"].ToString().ToLower() == Login1.UserName.ToLower())
                            {
                             item[field.InternalName] = var_newemail;
                             curWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                             item.Update(); //throws error when not logged in as administrator
                             curWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                             break; 
                            }
                        }

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

may want to try adding something like this to you code:

```
    string usName = null;
            SPClaimProviderManager mgr = SPClaimProviderManager.Local;
            if (mgr != null)
            {
                var claim = new SPClaim(SPClaimTypes.UserLogonName,
                                        SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName,
                                        "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string",
                                        SPOriginalIssuers.Format(SPOriginalIssuerType.Windows));
                usName = mgr.EncodeClaim(claim);



so in your code just try adding:

SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                {
                    using (SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site)
                   {

 **if (site.DoesUserHavePermissions(usName,SPBasePermissions.ViewPages))
{**


                        SPWeb curWeb = site.OpenWeb();

                        SPList userList = SPContext.Current.Web.SiteUserInfoList;
                        StringBuilder queryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                        queryBuilder.Append(@"<Query>");
                        queryBuilder.Append(@"<OrderBy>");
                        queryBuilder.Append(@"<FieldRef Name='Title' />");
                        queryBuilder.Append(@"</OrderBy>");
                        queryBuilder.Append(@"<Where>");
                        queryBuilder.Append(@"<Eq>");
                        queryBuilder.Append(@"<FieldRef Name='Title' />");
                        queryBuilder.Append(@"<Value Type='Text'>" + var_UserName + "</Value>");
                        queryBuilder.Append(@"</Eq>");
                        queryBuilder.Append(@"</Where>");
                        queryBuilder.Append(@"</Query>");
                        SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                        query.Query = queryBuilder.ToString();
                        SPListItemCollection oSPListItemCollection = userList.GetItems(query);
                        SPField field = userList.Fields.GetField("E-Mail");

                        foreach (SPItem item in oSPListItemCollection)
                        {
                            if (item["Title"].ToString().ToLower() == Login1.UserName.ToLower())
                            {
                             item[field.InternalName] = var_newemail;
                             curWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                             item.Update(); //throws error when not logged in as administrator
                             curWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                             break; 
                            }
                        }
}

                    }
                });
```

Comment: Thanks ironman99. I would've tried that but i found a simpler answer myself. And it checks whether user has priviledges. But i don't want that, i want the code to execute come what may. So here's my answer

Answer (score 0):

The thing is: 
Don't use "context" to create the spSite object since it won't create the object with elevated privileges but with the privileges of the user who execute this code, which may cause an exception/error.
So i just removed Context object and it works for any user. BINGO :) Like this:

```
string var_UserName = myUsername;
string var_newemail = mynewemail@abc.com;
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
               using (SPSite site = new SPSite(Page.Request.Url.ToString())) //Change 1
               {
                    SPWeb curWeb = site.OpenWeb();

                    SPList userList = curWeb.Lists["User Information List"]; //Change 2
                    StringBuilder queryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    queryBuilder.Append(@"<Query>");
                    queryBuilder.Append(@"<OrderBy>");
                    queryBuilder.Append(@"<FieldRef Name='Title' />");
                    queryBuilder.Append(@"</OrderBy>");
                    queryBuilder.Append(@"<Where>");
                    queryBuilder.Append(@"<Eq>");
                    queryBuilder.Append(@"<FieldRef Name='Title' />");
                    queryBuilder.Append(@"<Value Type='Text'>" + var_UserName + "</Value>");
                    queryBuilder.Append(@"</Eq>");
                    queryBuilder.Append(@"</Where>");
                    queryBuilder.Append(@"</Query>");
                    SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
                    query.Query = queryBuilder.ToString();
                    SPListItemCollection oSPListItemCollection = userList.GetItems(query);
                    SPField field = userList.Fields.GetField("E-Mail");

                    foreach (SPItem item in oSPListItemCollection)
                    {
                        if (item["Title"].ToString().ToLower() == Login1.UserName.ToLower())
                        {
                         item[field.InternalName] = var_newemail;
                         curWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                         item.Update(); //throws error when not logged in as administrator
                         curWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                         break; 
                        }
                    }

                }
            });
```